# Installing GMP on MacOS X with Xcode

Tags: c++, c, macos, xcode4, gmp

I'm trying to use the GMP library in my C and C++ programs.
I do code using the Xcode.
I followed the instructions to install the GMP on my machine and I end up with a folder "~/usr/local/gmp-5.0.5" which contains the gmp.h file.

How can I make my programs to see this library? if I decided to save my programs on desktop for example???

Where is the best place to install the gmp-5.0.5???
Using include "gmp.h" will show the error "file not found".

Comment: one of the previous post talks about GMP configuration on MAC hope you find [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965990/why-cant-nettle-2-4s-configure-find-gmp-5-0-2) useful.

Answer (score 14):

I have done it this way:

Download GMP from https://gmplib.org/ (gmp-6.0.0a.tar.lz)
Download lzip from http://www.nongnu.org/lzip/lzip.html (lzip-1.16.tar.gz)

1. install lzip

   - extract it: tar -xvf lzip-1.16.tar.gz
   - cd lzip-1.16
   - ./configure
   - make
   - make check
   - make install (run it with sudo if you receive permission denied message)
2. install gmp

   - copy the gmp-6.0.0a.tar.lz file to /usr/local/lib (do it with sudo)
   - extract the lz: lzip -d gmp-6.0.0a.tar.lz
   - extract the tar: tar -xvf gmp-6.0.0a.tar
   - cd gmp-6.0.0/
   - ./configure
   - make
   - make check
   - make install (run it with sudo if you receive permission denied message)

Comment: We could download the gmp-6.0.0a.tar.bz2, rather than the *.lz version. The command to extract bz2 is bzip2 -d -k gmp-6.0.0a.tar.bz2. The following steps are the same.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you install the library in `/usr/local`, you will be able to simply `#include <gmp.h>` and add `-lgmp` to your linker settings (Linking > Other Linker Flags).
2. If you insist on putting the library in your home directory, say `~/local`, then you will need to add `~/local/include` to your header search paths (Search Paths > Header Search Paths), `~/local/lib` to your library search paths (Search Paths > Library Search Paths).  These are under the project or target settings.  You will also need to add `-lgmp` as above.

**Note about architectures:** LibGMP is rather unique in that it will choose the target architecture at compile-time, and it usually chooses a 64-bit target where available.  If your project is 32-bit and your GMP is 64-bit, linking will fail.

LibGMP does this because the kind of operations it does are *much* faster on 64-bit architectures.  Multiplying large integers can be around 4x as fast on 64-bit as 32-bit.

**Warning:** Your project will not run on other people's computers unless they install GMP first.

**Warning 2:** If you statically link with GMP to simplify installation, you are required to open-source your application.  Don't statically link unless you are okay with that.

Comment: Regarding the warning: he could just link statically to GMP, in which case people will not need to install it in order to run the application.

Comment: @MihaiTodor: If he statically links to the GMP, he has to open-source his application.