# Pycrypto install fatal error: gmp.h file not found

Tags: python, osx-mountain-lion, gmp, pycrypto

It seems like there are a number of people who have had a similar problem, however, after much searching I haven't been able to find a solution that works with my particular architecture.  I'm trying to install Pycrypto (as a subsidiary of Fabric) to no avail.

I'm running Mac 10.8.2, python 2.7.3 via Homebrew, and XCode 4.6 -- installing with pip or easy_install (I've tried both).  From what I can tell, the problem could either be with respect to my version of XCode or because of my libraries.  The Command Line Tools for XCode have been installed and I have tried placing `setenv ARCHFLAGS "-arch i386 -arch x86_64"` in my .cshrc file.  I have also tried `ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer /Developer`.  As for the libraries, I've tried linking them via `ln -s /usr/local/lib/libgmp.dylib /usr/lib/libgmp.dylib` - but that also didn't work.

The error is always the same (see below) no matter what angle I attempt.  Any and all help would be appreciated.

```
/usr/local/share/python% pip install pycrypto
Downloading/unpacking pycrypto
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pycrypto

Installing collected packages: pycrypto
  Running setup.py install for pycrypto
    building 'Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath' extension
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -fwrapv -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/_fastmath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/src/_fastmath.o
src/_fastmath.c:36:11: fatal error: 'gmp.h' file not found
# include <gmp.h>
          ^
1 error generated.
error: command '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
Complete output from command /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/var/folders/ym/v8l23q_x2xz_qhx3m84n6ym00005fr/T/pip-build/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/ym/v8l23q_x2xz_qhx3m84n6ym00005fr/T/pip-Xb7nGV-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
running install

running build

running build_py

running build_ext

running build_configure

building 'Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath' extension

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -fwrapv -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/_fastmath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/src/_fastmath.o

src/_fastmath.c:36:11: fatal error: 'gmp.h' file not found

# include <gmp.h>

      ^

1 error generated.

error: command '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain    /usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/var/folders/ym/v8l23q_x2xz_qhx3m84n6ym00005fr/T/pip-build/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/ym/v8l23q_x2xz_qhx3m84n6ym00005fr/T/pip-Xb7nGV-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /var/folders/ym/v8l23q_x2xz_qhx3m84n6ym00005fr/T/pip-build/pycrypto
Storing complete log in /Users/me/.pip/pip.log
```

The error when I try to call Fabric:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/share/python/fab", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2815, in <module>
working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 690, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 588, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pycrypto>=2.1,!=2.4
```

Comment: I found that `brew uninstall gmp ; brew install gmp` fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized that the root of my problem was in an incompatibility between the versions of Fabric and Pycrypto.  Once I downgraded my version of Fabric to 1.2.6, I no longer got the errors above.  Then, I used the [tutorial](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/installation.html#pycrypto) as a jumping off point.  However, despite the tutorial and the older version of Fabric, I still got the `PyCrypto >= 2.1, !=2.4` error.  I eventually installed Pycrypto 2.2 from source (since apparently `pip` will only install v. 2.0.1 even when designating `pip -Iv install pycrypto==2.2` per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip) and v. 2.6 resulted in the `gmp.h` error).  Finally, everything worked.

Answer (score 128):

If you use Homebrew, this should do the trick:

```
brew install gmp
env "CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib" pip install pycrypto
```

Using env will only make it work for that invocation. If you need to install pycrypto at a later time in this session export the variable instead.

```
export "CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib" 
pip install pycrypto
```

Comment: thanks.  `env "CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/gmp -L/usr/lib/gmp"  pip install pycrypto` worked for me on Solaris 11.3.

Comment: How portable do you think this is? Do you think it would break anything if I made the same change running on e.g. Centos? (I'm running the `pip install` from inside a script.)

Answer (score 6):

I was able to get PyCrypto to install using the following command:

```
CFLAGS=-I/opt/local/include pip install pycrypto
```

I have GMP installed via MacPorts, running on OSX 10.8.3 with Python 2.7.2 from python.org.  In this case I am installing into a virtualenv.

I do get the following warning when PyCrypto is used, but it still works:

```
/Users/me/.virtualenvs/blah/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Util/number.py:57: PowmInsecureWarning: Not using mpz_powm_sec.  You should rebuild using libgmp >= 5 to avoid timing attack vulnerability.
  _warn("Not using mpz_powm_sec.  You should rebuild using libgmp >= 5 to avoid timing attack vulnerability.", PowmInsecureWarning)
```

Comment: I needed to add also -L/usr/local/lib to CFLAGS. On Catalina.

Answer (score 2):

Simply linking gmppylib is not helpful because pycrpto needs to compile some C files which will include gmp.h.  You should have the GMP library installed which will contain gmp.h. It seems you have to install GMP on your Mac OS. The following two links should be helpful to you.

- [Installation of gmp and mpfr on Mac OS X](http://math.digi2.jp/math/mp/mpfr/install.html)
- [Installing GMP on MacOS X with Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12852228/installing-gmp-on-macos-x-with-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix that worked for me:

https://medium.com/software-bugs/84afab886a1e

You need to create a symlink based on the installation header include path (-I) in but crash. Example:

building 'Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath' extension

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/X11/include -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -fwrapv -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ **-I/usr/include/ -**I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/_fastmath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/src/_fastmath.o

src/_fastmath.c:36:11: fatal error: 'gmp.h' file not found