# Cannot link gmp: library not found for -lgmp

Tags: gcc, clang, macos-big-sur, gmp, apple-m1

I'm trying to install `fastecdsa` on macOS BigSur (M1 chip) by running

```sh
(venv) $ pip3 install fastecdsa
```

and even though I previously installed `gmp`:

```sh
$ brew install gmp
```

it cant find the lib, no matter what I do

```
    src/curve.h:4:10: fatal error: 'gmp.h' file not found
    #include "gmp.h"
```

Although the error changed when I created a symlink

```sh
ln -s /opt/homebrew/include/gmp.h /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
```

and now I get:

```
    ld: library not found for -lgmp
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

I also tried:

- passing the path via env [`CFLAGS`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35753259/1633783), `LDFLAGS` and both via global env export (`export CFLAGS=...`)

```
LDFLAGS=-L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib pip3 install fastecdsa
```

```
CFLAGS=-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include pip3 install fastecdsa
```

- `xcode-select --install`
- endlessly `brew uninstall gmp` and `brew install gmp`, even `brew reinstall gmp` and `brew unlink gmp`
- installing rosetta2
- turning it off and on again

I can't put my finger on it :(

Answer (score 1):

You may have resolved this by now, but just to say that I ran into something similar, and the solution for me was to tell `ld` to look in the homebrew library path. Run this/add it to `~/.profile`:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/homebrew/lib
export INCLUDE_PATH=$INCLUDE_PATH:/opt/homebrew/include
```

(I didn't need INCLUDE_PATH in my case, but it looks like you might!)

After that, perhaps your python commands will start working!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved a similar problem on my Mac. The problem is

```
pip install fastecdsa

...
      In file included from src/curve.c:1:
      src/curve.h:4:10: fatal error: 'gmp.h' file not found
      #include "gmp.h"
               ^~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/local/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fastecdsa
Failed to build fastecdsa
ERROR: Could not build wheels for fastecdsa, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

The solution is

1. Install GMP

```
brew install gmp
```

2. If you have installed GMP, make sure it's linked

```
brew link gmp
```

Read the warnings. If it tells you to relink, do it.

```
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.3.0
To relink, run:
  brew unlink gmp && brew link gmp
```

3. Pass the `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` with above links to `pip install`

```bash
CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.3.0/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.3.0/lib pip install fastecdsa
```

The catch is - make sure the paths to the GMP header and lib are correct.

In my case, they are respectively

- `/usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.3.0/include`
- `/usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.3.0/lib`

If you cd into the header directory, you should see `gmp.h` there. If you cd into the lib directory, you should see `libgmp.a` and `libgmp.dylib` there.

Comment: The CFLAGS and LDFLAGS trick (step 3) did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh1wt.png)

use the setup.py to install and modify the setup.py as the image

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.