# Installing & Finding GMP under OSX

Tags: c++, macos

around a few days I am troubling an issue when installing the SCIP suite. SCIP requests the GMP Library:

```
src/rational.h:32:10: fatal error: 'gmp.h' file not found
#include "gmp.h"
```

To this end, I tried to install gmp according to the following two ressources:

- [Installing GMP on MacOS X with Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12852228/installing-gmp-on-macos-x-with-xcode) I tried gmp-6.1.0 aswell as gmp-6.0.0a
- http://macappstore.org/gmp/ I checked the link via brew link gmp

I aswell checked and adjusted the shell paths, but it unfortunately does not work, the same errors occur as described above.

Could some of you recommend me another way to solve my problem?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By the way, the easiest way to install `gmp` on a Mac is by using `homebrew`. You go to the [homebrew website](http://brew.sh) and copy the one-line installation script and paste it into Terminal. Then you can find any package you want like this:

```
brew search gmp
```

and install very simply with

```
brew install gmp
```

Anyway, back to your actual question... I suspect you have not set the *Header search path* correctly in Xcode.

First, you need to find where `gmp.h` is located, so do this in Terminal:

```
find /usr /opt -name "gmp.h"
```

I am guessing here that it is under `/usr` or `/opt`, but if you know you installed `gmp` elsewhere, replace `/usr /opt` with that place.

**Sample Output**

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gmp/include/gmp.h
```

That will tell you where it is located, then take the containing directory (i.e. the answer above MINUS the "gmp.h" bit at the end) and add it into Xcode *Build Settings* in the area marked in blue on the diagram. To get to the blue area, click first on the area marked in green, then yellow, then blue.

[image]

Comment: There  is more information here that you can easily adapt... http://stackoverflow.com/a/34341219/2836621

Comment: Thank you so much! :-) I did not install the command line in xcode properly.

Answer (score 0):

After following the answer from @Mark Setchell I hit lots of `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:` for every gmp API I had inside my C code.

To fix the error, I added a Linker flag inside my xCode project.

[image]