# Where does GMP get installed to by default on Mac High Sierra?

Tags: macos, gmp, macos-high-sierra

I just downloaded the tar.bz2 file for GMP 6.1.2 on Mac High Sierra.  After configuring, making, and installing everything without errors, I couldn't figure out what my path to GMP actually was.  The web site said my default path would be /usr/local, but I don't see anything in there

```
localhost:gmp-6.1.2 davea$ ls /usr/local
CODEOFCONDUCT.md  Cellar      LICENSE.txt  SUPPORTERS.md  heroku   mysql            packager       rmagic-2.21  var
CONTRIBUTING.md   Frameworks  Library      bin        include  mysql-5.5.46-osx10.8-x86_64  php5           sbin
Caskroom      Homebrew    README.md    etc        lib      opt              remotedesktop  share
```

Where does GMP get installed to on Mac OS X (High Sierra)?

Comment: Amy reason not to make life simple and use **homebrew** to install it? `brew install gmp`

Comment: Did you bother checking some of those subdirectories? Or rerun configure with the -h option and read that text?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I'm happy to install with homebrew but the reason I need the path is because I want to build PHP from source configured with GMP and I need the GMP install directory when I run the "./configure" command.  What's the GMP install path with Homebrew?

Comment: Headers will be in `/usr/local/include` and libraries will be in `/usr/local/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be installed. Check subdirectories. Also run find command to match if expected libraries are really installed or not.

Comment: The docs said the install diretoy would be /usr/local and there's nothinng in there called "gmp" or any derivitive of that.  So are teh docs wrong?  If so, what is teh directory (i.e. where does it install for y ou)?

Comment: @Dave: As mentioned in your question's comments, try installing using homebrew. Also, did you find a directory named `Cellar` in `/user/local`?
Also visit this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35360885/installing-finding-gmp-under-osx