# brew installed gcc can't find brew installed gmp

Tags: macos, gcc, homebrew

I used brew install gcc, and brew install gmp.
However clang could compiler with option "-lgmpxx" and succeed while g++ failed
I used this command:

```
g++ bn_p.cpp -o bn_p.out -lgmpxx -lgmp -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp
```

And it said:

```
fatal error: gmpxx.h: No such file or directory
4 | #include <gmpxx.h>
```

Comment: Brew link gmp is already done

Comment: Not very much sure about brew, but I guess you should add the path to `gmpxx.h` to your include path, by flag `-I`.

Comment: Search for the path where `gmxx.h` resides and while compiling add this `-I /whateverpath/`

Comment: I have tried -I, stilled doesn't work, Thank you anyway!

Comment: I think there are some problems with link

Comment: i have mac too but i use `macports` generally for packages. So can’t help you much with it. Hope someone else gives you the solution.

Comment: I have solved this by following your advice actually. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Mihir mind adding this as a response so Zijie Han can accept it? This would mark this question as answered.

Comment: @bfontaine, what i told was just an alternative. The question specifically asks about `homebrew` and I know very little about it. My best guess is that `macports` generally asks root privileges so it may have been able to do the correct setup somehow. (sounds nonsense to me tbh)

Answer (score 0):

Installing using home-brew doesn't seem the right approach, I suggest following the instruction of another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29448476/10210279) which seems to follow some kind of best practice

If you still prefer to use your installation using brew, I resolved my problem by running

```
brew info gmp
```

which returns the installation path, for example mine was:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gmp/6.2.1_1
```

then you just need to include the include folder as a library search path in your compilation command, for example:

```
g++ main.cpp -o app -I /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gmp/6.2.1_1/include
```